# No legend from geom_tile() and unable to add legend manually

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot figure out why this plot doesn't produce a legend. I am also unable to manually add legend using scale_fill_manual or other techniques.

Thankful for all suggestions and solutions

Make data frame to plot

```
 df <- data.frame(
 x=factor( ordered( 1:5 ), labels = c("Minimal", "Minor", "Moderate", "Major", "Massive" ) ),
 y=rep(1:5, each=5), 
 z=1:25)
```

Plot

```
   library(ggplot2)

    ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_tile(col="purple", 
        fill = c("seagreen1", "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "yellow2",
                 "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "seagreen2",   "yellow2",  "yellow2",
                 "seagreen2", "seagreen2",   "yellow2",   "yellow3", "yellow3",
                 "seagreen2",    "yellow2",   "yellow3",    "yellow3", "tomato3",
                 "yellow2",    "yellow3",   "yellow3",    "tomato3", "tomato3"), 
        size=1) +

   scale_y_discrete(name ="Probability of Invasion", limits= c("Very unlikely", "Unlikely", 
   "Moderately likely", "Likely", "Very likely" ), expand = c(0, 0)) +
   scale_x_discrete(name ="Impact", limits= c("Minimal", "Minor", "Moderate", "Major", "Massive" ), 
   expand = c(0, 0)) +
   labs(title = "Risk") +
   theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
   axis.title=element_text(size=25, face="bold"),
   plot.title = element_text(size=25, face="bold"))
```

Comment: As far as I know it will only produce a legend if colour or fill is inside `aes()`.

Comment: I have tried that too, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure how your output should be, but try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, 
               y = y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = as.factor(z)), # added fill to aes, the as.factor is here to make the values discrete
            col = "purple", 
            size = 1) +

  scale_y_discrete(name = "Probability of Invasion",
                   limits= c("Very unlikely", "Unlikely", 
                             "Moderately likely", "Likely", "Very likely" ),
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name ="Impact", 
                   limits= c("Minimal", "Minor", "Moderate", "Major", "Massive" ), 
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  # added manual colors
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("seagreen1", "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "yellow2",
                             "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "seagreen2",   "yellow2",  "yellow2",
                             "seagreen2", "seagreen2",   "yellow2",   "yellow3", "yellow3",
                             "seagreen2",    "yellow2",   "yellow3",    "yellow3", "tomato3",
                             "yellow2",    "yellow3",   "yellow3",    "tomato3", "tomato3")) +
  labs(title = "Risk") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.title = element_text(size=25, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=25, face="bold"))
```

Comment: Well, that was easy! I was missing the as.factor(z) part. Thank you very much for a quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option by adding the desired color as an extra column to the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x=factor( ordered( 1:5 ), labels = c("Minimal", "Minor", "Moderate", "Major", "Massive" )),
  y=rep(1:5, each=5), 
  z=1:25, 
  col=c("seagreen1", "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "yellow2",
        "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "yellow2",  "yellow2",
        "seagreen2", "seagreen2", "yellow2", "yellow3", "yellow3",
        "seagreen2", "yellow2", "yellow3", "yellow3", "tomato3",
        "yellow2",   "yellow3", "yellow3", "tomato3", "tomato3"))

#correctly order the labels
df$col<-factor(as.character(df$col), levels=c("seagreen1", "seagreen2", "yellow2", "yellow3", "tomato3"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=col), col="purple",  size=1, show.legend = TRUE) +

  scale_y_discrete(name ="Probability of Invasion", 
                   limits= c("Very unlikely", "Unlikely", "Moderately likely", "Likely", "Very likely" ),
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name ="Impact", 
                   limits= c("Minimal", "Minor", "Moderate", "Major", "Massive" ), 
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(title = "Risk") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title=element_text(size=25, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=25, face="bold"))+
#use scale fill identity to set labels, name and color
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend", labels=c("low", "medlow", "med", "medhigh", "high"), 
                       name="Risk level")
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually a nicer solution!